# Python Pubsub + Subprocess complaining about logger handler, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-platform, subprocess, google-cloud-pubsub

**EDIT: Solution found [in this new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283001/how-do-i-create-assign-a-logging-handler-for-google-cloud-pubsub)**

I am using modified sample code to pull PubSub messages generated from Object Change Notifications. It works fine so far, in the **Deb9 VM**.
In a python dictionary named message.data, there is this pair

> "name":"folder2/1.testing"

Next, I need to pass strings along to issue unix commands, which I use subprocess for.

In a separate test script, but executed in **native Windows 10**, I have found that

```
testdictionary = {"name":"folder2/1.testing"}

dirpath = "~/subfolder1/"
namepath = testdictionary["name"]
fullpath = dirpath + namepath
subprocess.call(["echo abcd '/%{0}'".format(fullpath)])
```

to be valid code, echoing

> abcd ~/subfolder1/folder2/1.testing

in the **Win10 terminal**.

However, when attempting to combine the code, and **run in a Deb9 VM**, I get this error returned:

> No handlers could be found for logger "google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.streaming_pull_manager"

Here is my full combined code (tested working perfectly before adding the dirpath to subprocess lines):

```
import time
import subprocess

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

project_id = "redacted"
subscription_name = "redacted"

def receive_messages_with_custom_attributes(project_id, subscription_name):
    """Receives messages from a pull subscription."""
    # [START pubsub_subscriber_sync_pull_custom_attributes]

    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
        project_id, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        print('Received message: {}'.format(message.data))
        if message.attributes:
            #print('Attributes:')
            for key in message.attributes:
                value = message.attributes.get(key);
                #commented out to not print to terminal
                #which should not be necessary
                #print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
        message.ack()

        dirpath = "~/subfolder1/"
        namepath = message.data["name"]
        print(namepath)
        fullpath = dirpath + namepath
        print(fullpath)
        print("this is before subprocess")
        subprocess.call(["echo", "abcd", '/%{0}'.format(fullpath)], shell=True)
            #subprocess.call(["bash job-submit.sh -r hg19.fa.mmi -f '/%{0}' -o file_out.bam".format(fullpath)], shell=True)


    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
    # The subscriber is non-blocking, so we must keep the main thread from
    # exiting to allow it to process messages in the background.
    print('Listening for messages on {}'.format(subscription_path))
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
    # [END pubsub_subscriber_sync_pull_custom_attributes]

receive_messages_with_custom_attributes(project_id, subscription_name)
```

I am not familiar with coding in general, and will greatly appreciate if someone can tell me what to change in the code to get desired behavior instead of logger errors.

I've seen something about `import logging`, but other questions had contexts too different from mine, and solutions aren't really transferable.

Full returns on the console with a test file:

```
Listening for messages on projects/[redacted]
Received message: {
  "kind": "storage#object",
  "id": "[redacted]/0.testing/1548033442364022",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[redacted]/o/BSD%2F0.testing",
  "name": "BSD/0.testing",
  "bucket": "[redacted]",
  "generation": "1548033442364022",
  "metageneration": "1",
  "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
  "timeCreated": "2019-01-21T01:17:22.363Z",
  "updated": "2019-01-21T01:17:22.363Z",
  "storageClass": "MULTI_REGIONAL",
  "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2019-01-21T01:17:22.363Z",
  "size": "0",
  "md5Hash": "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==",
  "mediaLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/[redacted]/o/BSD%2F0.testing?generation=1548033442364022&alt=media",
  "crc32c": "AAAAAA==",
  "etag": "CPb0uvvZ/d8CEAE="
}

No handlers could be found for logger "google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.streaming_pull_manager"
```

Further traceback after I Ctrl + C:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "ps_parse_pull.py", line 47, in <module>
    receive_messages_with_custom_attributes(project_id, subscription_name)
  File "ps_parse_pull.py", line 44, in receive_messages_with_custom_attributes
    time.sleep(60)
KeyboardInterrupt
Exception in thread Thread-Heartbeater (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/heartbeater.py", line 40, in heartbeat
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 283, in heartbeat
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py", line 453, in is_active
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 168, in acquire
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Exception in thread Thread-2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 207, in consume_request_iterator
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'return_from_user_request_generator'
Exception in thread Thread-LeaseMaintainer (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/leaser.py", line 103, in maintain_leases
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/histogram.py", line 142, in percentile
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Your `subprocess` code has a number of issues, but they seem completely unrelated to the `logging` question. Can you split this up into multiple questions? Or maybe just read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538

Comment: Also, without a shell, `~` doesn't get expanded, and adding another slash in front of it is definitely not correct.

Comment: Your `subprocess` call *might* work on Windows, but definitely fails on MacOS and probably on Linux.

Comment: Apologies, I assumed the whole problem was being caused by logging. And I should have mentioned that my mini tests were done in Windows, while the combined code was run in Debian9 VM. I should replace `~` with `/home`, right? And the link, while informative, is slightly inaccessible. To summarize, is it as simple as replacing `subprocess.call` with `subprocess.run`?

Comment: No, you have I think three or four of the common errors outlined in that post. `subprocess.call` is fine but you can't pass in a single shell command in brackets.  You want either `call("your command", shell=True)` or `call(["your", "command"])` but not this ungodly mongrel hybrid.

Comment: The tilde expansion can most elegantly be handled by `os.path.expanduser()`

Comment: The commented-out line in your real script should be `subprocess.call(["bash", "job-submit.sh", "-r", "hg19.fa.mmi", "-f", '/%{0}'.format(fullpath), "-o", "file_out.bam"])` (or equivalently take out the square brackets around the string and leave the `shell=True`; but seeing as you are not using the shell for anything useful, that seems silly) and I would look into getting rid of the explicit `bash` too.

Comment: Having said that, you probably should prefer `check_call` over plain `call` at the very least.  `run` offers many additional conveniences but if all you need is to whack this code into shape, maybe don't go there yet.

Comment: For the logging error, do you just get that printed to standard error, or is there a traceback? If so, please include the full trace.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with subprocess, that was a nightmare to learn and I obviously wasn't a good student, but I'm glad you tamed the monster I janked together. There is only a traceback after I stop the script with Ctrl+C, and I have included that. Without stopping the script, there's no further messages after the standard error.

Comment: Then I would surmise that the warning is harmless per se.

Comment: But neither the `print(stuff)` nor `subprocess.call(stuff)` are executing. The console returns go straight from the pubsub attributes to "No handlers ...." error

Comment: I have added a few more lines of basic `print(var)` and `print("string")` code before the `subprocess` code, as well as the full console log, to the OP. The basic `print` code aren't executing, so there's a problem in the python setup, even before the `subprocess` code.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure the entire `subprocess` thrng should be removel from a [mcve].

Comment: I have made a [new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54283001/how-do-i-create-assign-a-logging-handler-for-google-cloud-pubsub) which is much clearer :)